# How to use express middleware, with parameters getting from router link

Tags: node.js, express

I want to do something like:

```
function is_member(user_id){
    return function(req, res, next) {
        //do something
    }
}

app.get('/:user_id', is_member(user_id), (req, res, next) => {
    //do something
})
```

How can I archive this. doing app.get('/:user_id', is_member(req.params.user_id) is not working, and I'm currently doing app.params('user_id') to check something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A middleware must be a function.

When you give a middleware and call it, that means '()', then instead of the actual function its return value will be used in place of the middleware, and it wont work. But here you are returning a funciton, so it must work. but the problem is the place where you are trying too access the params.The req.params.user_id is not working in your implementation is because you are accessing it in a place where it does not exist. It must be accessed inside the middelware and not during assigning it.  So always pass the 'reference' of the function and don't call it. See the example below:

```
function is_member(req, res, next){
   let userId = req.params.user_id;
   // do something with the userId
   // After completing the logic, call next.
   next();
}

app.get('/:user_id', is_member, (req, res, next) => {
    //do something
    // After logic, either call next or send response by res.send();
})
```

Comment: @ThuanDucChu   Would be great to mark it as answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Thank you for your notice. I'm starting to use stackoverflow, so i'm sorry for the late mark.